# Cross product in hive due to "OR" condition

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am trying to join two big tables (in below example, these are table a and b) by two conditions with an "OR". This particular join condition (with "OR") is termed as the cross product by Hive. Do we have any specific reason for this?

```
with Emp as
(
select 1 as id, 1 as mid, 'Praveen' as name
union all 
select 2,200, 'Naveen'
union all
select 3,3, 'Sachin'
)
select a.id,b.mid,a.name 
from emp a left join emp b
on (a.id = b.id OR a.id = b.mid)
;
```

Here is the warning message -

```
Warning: Shuffle Join JOIN[18][tables = [a, b]] in Stage 'Stage-1:MAPRED' is a cross product
```

Comment: This is just a warning that the condition in the ON clause may result to the cartesian product of the joined tables and this is going to be a lengthy and expensive process. In your case with a dataset of only 3 rows you should not worry but a warning is a warning.

Comment: @forpas Agree but I am actually dealing with two huge tables (the above example i created just to simulate the warning message). I am not sure why exactly an "OR" condition makes it a cartesian/cross join.